# simulate the number of samples to be statistic relevant using a non-paremetric paired test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, sample-size, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have an experiment where a group of subjects must learn to associate some sounds to images (say, sound 1-image 1, sound2-image 2,... soundN-imageN).

They do a memory test (we present sounds and images several times. If they think it is a correct pair, they should mark yes. Otherwise, mark no. (pre test)

Then, the subjects nap.

I play half the learned sounds during the nap, so N/2 sounds are played. They wake up and redo the test. (post test)

We test if playing sounds during napping increases memory by comparing the memory test before and after the nap.

My hypothesis is that their accuracy on the memory test for associating the N/2 sounds that were played will be higher than the half that wasn't played).

I need to find the number of pairs (played sound-image and unplayed sound to show to each subject to make the whole paired test statistically relevant.

I have decided to simulate it on Matlab.

So, as I don't have any prior information about the distributions, I suppose a distribution for the post-test accuracy on played and non-played sounds. This is a guess:

accuracy played (hitc)- ($\mu$ = 0.7, std = 0.2)
accuracy non played (hitu)- ($\mu$ = 0.5, std = 0.3)

Then, I loop on the number draw of played and unplayed sounds-image pairs (from N = 1 to N = 500) from both distributions and make a Wilcoxon paired test. Here is the code:

```
 samples = samples = (1:500)';
 hitc = samples.*normrnd(0.7,0.2,s_max,1); %played sounds accuracy after the nap
 hitu = samples.*normrnd(0.5,0.2,s_max,1); %nonplayed sounds accuracy after the nap
   for ii = 1:500
    p(ii) = signrank(hitc(1:ii),hitu(1:ii),'tail','right','alpha',0.05);
   end

%% pvalues scatter
   figure;
   scatter(1:500, p);
```

[image: This is the result plot]

By looking at this it seems that 5 or 6 pairs of played and unplayed sounds are engouh to get a p-value of 0.05.

However, this plot changes if I run the code again. So, I decided to make the same code run 100 times. Here is the modified code:

```
samples = (1:500)';

for kk = 1:100
   hitc = samples.*normrnd(0.7,0.2,s_max,1); 
   hitu = samples.*normrnd(0.5,0.2,s_max,1); 
   for ii = 1:500
    p(ii,kk) = signrank(hitc(1:ii),hitu(1:ii),'tail','right','alpha',0.05);
   end
```

end

```
%% pvalues scatter
figure;
hold on;
  for ii = 1:500  
    scatter(ii*ones(1,100), p(ii,:));
  end
```

plot(1:100,ones(100)*0.05,'Color','black');
ylabel('P values');
xlabel('No of pairs');
ylim([0 1]);
xlim([1 500])

The resulting plot is now:
[image: result of the modified code]

The horizontal line is p = 0.05.
I am interpreting that I need to show 50 pair to be statistically significant because there are no points on the graph that are above p = 0.05. Even if one realization tells me that 5 pairs are enough, if I run it repeatedly, the number of pairs that guarantee on all runs the 0.05 value is higher than 50.

My question is: Why would the runs be so different in the second plot? Is it because I am considering a high standard deviation for the distributions? Is it fair to model the distributions that way? How would we guess the distributions better?

Please let me know if I have modeled the problem correctly.